# Как создать очередь из взаимосвязанных REST API запросов?

Tags: javascript, rest, chrome-extension, тестирование, google-chrome-devtools

Имеется два независимых друг от друга REST API, для взаимосвязи которых используется/разрабатывается промежуточный сервис, который с определённым интервалом взаимодействует с ними обеими. Стоит отметить, что оба API недоступны для изменения, т.e. являются сторонними продуктами. Оба API поддерживают [OpenAPI v.3.0.1](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/main/versions/3.0.1.md).
Первое API (назовём его [CAD](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F) API) по своей сути предоставляет доступ к CAD файлам/сборкам и сопутствующей информации. GUI продукта реализовано на Java.
Второе API (назовём его [MES](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/MES) API) может взаимодействовать с физическими машинами/станками/линиями на производстве. GUI продукта реализовано на Angular v.9.1.11.

**Описание проблемы**
Как и у любых API, у них имеется определённая и иногда весьма запутанная логика. Например в MES API изменениe состояния сущности возможно только в определённом порядке: `Draft -> Tested -> onApproval -> Approved -> Published -> Rejected -> Archived -> Deleted`, т.е. после отклонения программы (`Rejected`) программу можно заархивировать или удалить, но отправить опять на тестирование или опубликовать не выйдет. Помимо этого некоторые состояния не могут быть установлены с помощью GUI, например состояние `Tested` для NC программы устанавливается конкретной физической машиной на производстве после эмуляции процесса.
Другими словами, некоторые состояния сущностей невозможно установить с помощью GUI, т.к. их ручное изменение не предполагается и приходится с помощью Swagger'а выполнять кучу взаимосвязанных запросов (иногда до 20 отдельных запросов). [Bearer](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/authentication/bearer-authentication/)-аутентификация также добавляет дополнительных действий тестировщикам.

Для решения возникшей проблемы/неудобств появилась идея: т.к. у MES API имеется Angular frontend, то почему бы не использовать его? Мы не можем его (Angular frontend) изменить, но можем разработать [расширение для Google Chrome DevTools](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv2/devtools/) и тогда:

- избавляемся от необходимости аутентификации;
- можем перехватывать все запросы к API и на их основе создавать один объект содержащий всю необходимую информацию вместо ручного выполнения запросов в Swagger;

Теперь о проблеме... Если все API запросы на Angular-frontend'e в MES API мы можем в автоматическом режиме "сливать" в один объект используя URL запросов для построения структуры объекта, то для выполнения тестов необходимо выполнять *конфигурируемые* очереди запросов используя получаемую информацию из запросов для построения новых. В Postman последних версий появилась похожая функциональность в виде [Flows](https://community.postman.com/t/user-feedback-postman-flows/28121) ([видео на YouTube](https://youtu.be/j-fkJLbOpjk)), но т.к. это ещё Beta, то багов там, как говорится, вагон и маленькая тележка. Помимо этого возникает чувство, что после выхода из beta эта функциональность перенесётся в платные версии продукта.
Как представляется решение... На странице тестируемой сущности в Angular-frontend'e тестировщик открывает панель разработчика (DevTools), переходит на вкладку расширения и либо выбирает ранее сконфигурированную очередь запросов, либо создаёт новую и запускает тест.
На данный момент: расширение для DevTools имеется, запросы к MES API перехватываются, объект автоматически собирается.

**Вопрос:** каким образом можно создать *конфигурируемые* очереди запросов к REST API? Возможно я пытаюсь изобрести велосипед с квадратными колёсами и в отрасли уже есть готовое решение/подход/способ для поставленной задачи?

P.S.: почему запросы именно конфигурируемые? Так как предполагается использование в целях тестирования, то каждый раз пересобирать/изменять расширение для Chrom'a тестировщикам сомнительное удовольствие.

---

### UPDATE

Изобретённый велосипед, тот, что на квадратных колёсах получился довольно мерзостным и поэтому было решено не мучать разные участки тела, а использовать Postman Flows...

Comment: а что, из расширения нельзя  модалку сделать с полями ввода?

Comment: @Дмытрык проблема не с UI. Конфигурацию при необходимости можно и на чистом JSON писать. Вопрос в том, как это конфигурировать и выполнять.